# Cannot get data stored using ckeditor to display without tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor

I am storing several data elements on a page using ckeditor to allow rich text and cut/paste from Work/Excel. The data is being saved with all the HTML tags as desired, however I can't seem to get this data to display on a page without the tags and back into html formatted content.

Know this has to be simple, but I've spent most of a day trying to figure it out with no joy.

One example
Data being saved: Stem #4 with some **bold** and *italics*

Data showing on page:

```
<p>Stem #4 with some <strong>bold </strong>font and<em> italics</em></p>
```

I am using a label for the output of the data:

```
 <td>
     <asp:Label ID="txt_Stem" runat="server" Text='<%#:Item.Stem %>' ></asp:Label>
 </td>
```

Using a multiline textbox with ckeditor for input:

```
<td><asp:TextBox ID="Stem" Columns="50" Rows="8" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" CssClass="ckeditor"></asp:TextBox>
           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" Text="* STEM Required" ControlToValidate="Stem" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
```

I have setup the script for replacing the label for output with ckeditor, but nothing is firing and still getting all the html tags. Looks even worse when the data is cut/paste from Word or Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<asp:Literal>` instead of `<asp:Label>` and set its `Mode` property to `PassThrough`:

```
<td>
    <asp:Literal ID="txt_Stem" runat="server" Text='<%#:Item.Stem %>' Mode="PassThrough"></asp:Literal>
</td>
```

The label control sends HTML encoded text, so if you view the page source in your browser you'll see for example `&lt` instead of `<`. The literal control allows you to send the text "as is" to the browser.

Be advised that sending the original text without encoding or filtering is a security risk (XSS) because it allows a malicious user to potentially send malicious code that ends up in your users' browsers.

Comment: Alzmon, tried using Literal with mode passthrough, still getting same results.

Comment: What do you see when you view the page source in your browser? Is it HTML Encoded? What do you see in the database (raw data in your table)?

Comment: new to building things in asp.net (first application) so pardon if I provide wrong/incomplete data. Do you mean the META tag? If so that is utf-8. Don't see anything that specifically addresses HTML Encoded. Raw data is exactly what is showing on page.

Comment: You mentioned your page shows `<p>Stem #4 with some <strong>bold </strong>font and<em> italics</em></p>`. When you "View Source" in your browser and find this text in the HTML code, do you see `<p>` or `&lt;p&gt;`? The second option is called "HTML Encoded".

Comment: source shows: &lt;p&gt;Here is a longer Stem with formatting&lt;strong&gt; bold&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;

Comment: And that is the problem. Instead of sending HTML to the browser, you're sending Encoded HTML that can be displayed safely in the browser but is not rendered as actual HTML. It's just showing what the HTML should be ... This means you're either saving the HTML already encoded into the database or encoding on the way out (ASP Label does that). You'll need to figure this out in your specific app.

Comment: Ok, something to dig into, but I have zero idea how to resolve. Storing HTML to the database is by intent as the data cannot be text only, can include simple Excel charts, formatting, greek letters, etc.

Comment: If you're storing encoded HTML (not plain HTML) you need to `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()` it before sending it to the browser.

Comment: Very new to this, I don't know how to apply HttpUtility.HtmlDecode() to the label/s or Literals.

Answer (score 0):

Ends up all that I had to do to make this work was to change this:

```
<asp:Label ID="txt_Stem" runat="server" Text='<%#:Item.Stem %>' ></asp:Label>
```

To this:

```
<asp:Label ID="txt_Stem" runat="server" Text='<%# Item.Stem %>' ></asp:Label>
```

The colon after <%# made all the difference.